# Which search data structure works best for sorted integer data?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures

I have a sorted integers of over a billion, which data structure do you think can exploited the sorted behavior? Main goal is to search items faster... 
Options I can think of -- 
1) regular Binary Search trees with recursively splitting in the middle approach.
2) Any other balanced Binary search trees should work well, but does not exploit the sorted heuristics..

Thanks in advance..

[Edit]
Insertions and deletions are very rare...
Also, apart from integers I have to store some other information in the nodes, I think plain arrays cant do that unless it is a list right?

Comment: Search only? An array would work just as well, and waste less space. It wouldn't support efficient insert/delete of course.

Comment: insertions and deletions are rare...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This really depends on what operations you want to do on the data.

If you are just searching the data and never inserting or deleting anything, just storing the data in a giant sorted array may be perfectly fine.  You could then use binary search to look up elements efficiently in O(log n) time.  However, insertions and deletions can be expensive since with a billion integers O(n) will hurt.  You could store auxiliary information inside the array itself, if you'd like, by just placing it next to each of the integers.

However, with a billion integers, this may be too memory-intensive and you may want to switch to using a bit vector.  You could then do a binary search over the bitvector in time O(log U), where U is the number of bits.  With a billion integers, I assume that U and n would be close, so this isn't that much of a penalty.  Depending on the machine word size, this could save you anywhere from 32x to 128x memory without causing too much of a performance hit.  Plus, this will increase the locality of the binary searches and can improve performance as well.  this does make it much slower to actually iterate over the numbers in the list, but it makes insertions and deletions take O(1) time.  In order to do this, you'd need to store some secondary structure (perhaps a hash table?) containing the data associated with each of the integers.  This isn't too bad, since you can use this sorted bit vector for sorted queries and the unsorted hash table once you've found what you're looking for.

If you also need to add and remove values from the list, a balanced BST can be a good option.  However, because you specifically know that you're storing integers, you may want to look at the more complex van Emde Boas tree structure, which supports insertion, deletion, predecessor, successor, find-max, and find-min all in O(log log n) time, which is exponentially faster than binary search trees.  The implementation cost of this approach is high, though, since the data structure is notoriously tricky to get right.

Another data structure you might want to explore is a bitwise trie, which has the same time bounds as the sorted bit vector but allows you to store auxiliary data along with each integer.  Plus, it's super easy to implement!

Hope this helps!

Comment: van Emde Boas, doesn't suit my needs, I want to store some more information in the node apart from just storing yes or no. Which I think, van emde can't do. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @Ringo- van Emde Boas can be modified to support having associated data by storing the value associated with each integer along with the integer data.  It's uncommon to see this, but it's definitely possible.

Comment: oh, thanks I will try these, also I tried tango trees, but those are very very complex and it is k*log(log(n)), where k hurts me, if integers are around a billion only. log(n) is comparable for k(log(logn)) if k = 5-10 and items are a billion

Answer (score 2):

The best data structure for searching sorted integers is an array.

You can search it with log(N) operations, and it is more compact (less memory overhead) than a tree.

And you don't even have to write any code (so less chance of a bug) -- just use `bsearch` from your standard library.

Comment: Can you explain? you mean i can have O(1) time? but how?

Comment: You can't have constant time, its O(logn) with binary search on an array. And array doesn't need pointers to nodes like a tree does.

Comment: well I agree with log(N), can't I do better?

Comment: In general, you can't do better than O(log(N)). Array *can* have arbitrary data (bsearch can search array of structures; or you can have a second "parallel" array with the additional data).

Comment: You CAN do better in the average case with interpolation search! see my answer

Answer (score 2):

With a sorted array the best you can archieve is with an interpolation search, that gives you log(log(n)) average time. It is essentially a binary search but don't divide the array in 2 sub arrays of the same size.
It's really fast and extraordinary easy to implement.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation_search

Don't let the worst case O(n) bound scares you, because with 1 billion integers it's pratically impossible to obtain.

Comment: well, it seems to depend on some characteristics of the data -- data should be uniformly distributed. else search can go linear. So it is not applicable to this problem, where I can't be sure of uniformity...

Comment: well if the range of the integer is the range of an 32 bit integer than you have 1 billion numbers in a 0 - 4billion range and it's impossible to have the worst case

Comment: give it a try; it only takes 5 minutes to implement

Comment: sure, will try it.
Yes, practically impossible for O(n) to reach, but even if 100 is bad for me, because BST requires only 30 comparisons..

Comment: to have linear time you MUST have numbers distributed in a EXPONENTIAL way; something like this: 2 4 8 16 ... up to 2 ^ 1000000000 in your case. And this is IMPOSSIBLE

Comment: i hope so. moreover you can avoid linear case mantaining a average log(log(n)) and a worst log(n), by simply switching to binary search if after, say 2 * log(log(n)) subdivision, you still hasn't find the number you was searching for

Answer (score 1):

O(1) solutions:

- Assuming 32-bit integers and a lot of ram:

A lookup table with size 2³² roughly (4 billion elements), where each index corresponds to the number of integers with that value.

- Assuming larger integers:

A really big hash table. The usual modulus hash function would be appropriate if you have a decent distribution of the values, if not, you might want to combine the 32-bit strategy with a hash lookup.

Comment: I don't think, this is good solution for me, because
1) hashing is resource intensive.
2) I can't afford a single collision.
3) for hashing a billion I will have to use hash of size of long int

Comment: @Ringo For 3), not at all. regular 32 bit ints would work fine. For 1) a binary search is more complex. Lookup to a hash is just one % (mod) operation. Why 2) ?

Comment: 3)for 32bit numbers, how can it be possible to have no collisions with 32 bit hashes, I sense collisions.
1)I agree BST is resource(space) intense but compare is cheaper, I can use some other features of BST, which I didn't mention

Comment: @Ringo If it is a requirement to have no collisions, a hash is out of the question of course. But again, why that requirement?

Comment: every item is very important for me, if I loose even a single item, application has no value.. it is related to incident response...

Comment: @Ringo A hash table does not lose stuff. Look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Collision_resolution for instance.